vscode makefile tools configuration with custom make environment
We have a C project which can be compiled via a custom make environment.
Our custom make environment can be launched via a script i.e.
bash start.sh
This sets up variables, paths, etc. and our central Makefile.mak which then includes the rest of makefiles. We then have targets for cleaning, compiling, etc.
This structure is most probably incompatible with how vscode's makefile tools extension is supposed to work i.e. it expects a Makefile in the workspace directory and it probably directly executes make here.
Any idea how we could configure this extension for our use-case?
Alternatively, is there a way we produce some artifacts from our custom build environment so the extension reads them and understand what we're doing? This would also be acceptable.
Our goal is to have intellisense running as currently all our C files are mostly grayed out due to pre-compile macros not being known by the vscode extension.

I am not very familiar with VS Code, but you don't have to use the makefile extension with Intellisense.  See here for other options.
If you want to use compile_commands.json to define the flags used by the compiler (including -I, -D, paths, etc. that it needs to locate your source code), you can consider using bear to generate a compile_commands.json file from your makefile environment.

Life saver! I didn't actually use compile_commands.json as it was easier for me to directly create a new c_cpp_properties.json file with the correct contents under configurations/defines and configurations/includePath.
